# Issue on Setting MinDate on DatePickerDialog android

Tags: android, android-activity, datepicker, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I am using `DatePickerDialog` in Android to select Date range, I am able to set the `minDate` and `MaxDate` in `LolliPop (5+)`. But while executing the same in below Lollipop it is throwing exception.

**Code Used:**

```
Calendar cal_currentDate=Calendar.getInstance();

cal_currentDate.set(cal_currentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal_currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1,cal_currentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

DatePickerDialog datepicker=new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),new OnDateSetListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {}                         },
          cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
          datepicker.show();
          datepicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis()); // here am setting Maximum date as current date
          cal.add(Calendar.MONTH,-3); // here am setting Minimum date 3 months less than current date         
          datepicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis());
          datepickerdialog.show();
```

***Result: Working fine in Android Lollipop.
Crashing with exception in other lower versions***

Here is the exception Message

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Time not between Sat Mar 21 18:23:16 GMT+00:00 2015 and Tue Apr 21 18:23:16 GMT+00:00 2015
            at android.widget.CalendarView.goTo(CalendarView.java:789)
            at android.widget.CalendarView.setMinDate(CalendarView.java:478)
            at android.widget.DatePicker.setMinDate(DatePicker.java:316)
            at com.teledna.moby.ui.Fragment_homeMenu$16.onCheckedChanged(Fragment_homeMenu.java:1124
```

Please help...

Comment: on which lower version are you checking?

Comment: @mukesh Have you find-out any solutions for this. I have same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
setMaxDate
```

doesn't work below Honeycomb.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the DatePickerDialog class to support Android versions earlier than API level 11.

Check the link:
[How to make a Custom DatePicker control with maximum and minimum date range in Android application](http://technet.weblineindia.com/mobile/how-to-make-a-custom-datepicker-control-with-maximum-and-minimum-date-range-in-android-application/)